# Trying to plot percent missing from dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn

I have an object named `'fs.missing_stats'`.  Here is a sample of the data.

```
fs.missing_stats.head(10)

                          missing_fraction
COMMONAREA_MEDI                     0.6953
COMMONAREA_MODE                     0.6953
COMMONAREA_AVG                      0.6953
NONLIVINGAPARTMENTS_AVG             0.6945
NONLIVINGAPARTMENTS_MEDI            0.6945
NONLIVINGAPARTMENTS_MODE            0.6945
LIVINGAPARTMENTS_MODE               0.6846
LIVINGAPARTMENTS_MEDI               0.6846
LIVINGAPARTMENTS_AVG                0.6846
FLOORSMIN_MEDI                      0.6751
```

I am trying to plot this data.  Here is the code that I'm testing.

```
import seaborn as sns
prod_count = pd.DataFrame(fs.missing_stats.sort_values(ascending=False).head(20))
plt.figure()
sns.barplot(fs.missing_stats.index, fs.missing_stats['missing_fraction'].values, alpha=0.8)
plt.title('Percent Missing')
plt.ylabel('Missing', fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel('Features', fontsize=12)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

I think that should be pretty close, but I am getting the following error.

```
TypeError: sort_values() missing 1 required positional argument: 'by'
```

Maybe something is wrong with the index; just a guess.  I'm not sure how to debug these kinds of things.

Comment: As per the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) `sort_values` accept a positional argument which is a **Name or list of names to sort by.**

Comment: You could try `fs.missing_stats.sort_index()` instead.

Comment: Oh, yeah, the fs.missing_stats.sort_index() worked.  However, everything is plotted, rather than the top 20 items.  How can I restrict the x-axis to the top 20 items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
import seaborn as sns
prod_count = pd.DataFrame(fs.missing_stats.sort_index().head(20))
plt.figure()
sns.barplot(fs.missing_stats[:20].index, fs.missing_stats[:20]['missing_fraction'].values, alpha=0.8)
plt.title('Percent Missing')
plt.ylabel('Missing', fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel('Features', fontsize=12)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Yeap, yeap.  It makes sense now.  Thanks so much.